# How to indent ONE line in Vscode by pressing Tab button? Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are some ways to do it. CMD + }, or press Tab when you select more than one line, but I want to change keybindings or install any plugin to make my  Tab button work as well as Shift + Tab do.

If there are any misunderstandings I will show an example:

[image]

When I press Shift + Tab the line goes left, but this line doesn't go right when I press only Tab

Comment: have you tried to go to preferences of vs code then settings and checking if it's disabled.
try answers from here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251820/visual-studio-code-format-is-not-using-indent-settings

Comment: Try the extension `Multi Command` to combine multiple commands into one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Keyboard Shortcuts
2. search for `indent line`
3. right-click on `Indent Line` entry, chose `Add Keybinding...`
4. in the popup box asking for a keybinding, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to
   accept

You'll get a custom keybinding added to the end of your `keybindings.json` that looks like this:

```
 {
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "editor.action.indentLines",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
 }
```

You may want to change that `"when"` clause to

`"when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"`

if you want it to work only when there is a selection in the line - otherwise you'll never be able to add a <kbd>Tab</kbd> anywhere but the beginning of a line.

Comment: This works great. Thank you. This is what I'm looking for

Comment: Good, please consider accepting the answer (click the checkmark) if this answer solved your question.  Thanks.