# VSCode: Markdown files indents list items with 3 spaces instead of a tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I have a .md file that contains

```
3. test
1. indent me
```

When I move the cursor to the left of "1." I get:

```
3. test
   1. indent me
```

where the indent is 3 spaces. How do I get it to be a tab with a width of 2 spaces? I have "Tab Size: 2" on the bottom of the editor, so idk why I'm still indenting with 3 spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: format is not using indent settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251820/visual-studio-code-format-is-not-using-indent-settings)

Comment: .                          no                            .,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Solved. I was using markdown all in one and had to change indentationSize to inherit

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy! Your solution worked for me. You should post your solution as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was using [markdown all in one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) and had to change `indentationSize` to inherit

Comment: fyi the full setting is `"markdown.extension.list.indentationSize": "inherit"`

Comment: I had to use the full `inherit` example from @chantey as well as the disable format on save from @josephdpurcell.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I'm having to address eslint, prettier, and vscode. They all seem to be wanting 3 spaces for an indent and I am confused, but here I am.

1. Edit your `.vscode/settings.json` like so:

```json
{
  "markdown.extension.toc.slugifyMode": "bitbucket-cloud",
  "markdown.extension.list.indentationSize": "inherit",
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4
  }
}
```

Note: the `bitbucket-cloud` line is probably not needed, I'm including it JUST in case its relevant.

2. Edit your `.prettierrc` like so:

```json
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.md",
      "options": {
        "tabWidth": 4
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Edit your `.eslintrc.json` like so:

```json
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.md"],
      "extends": [],
      "rules": {
        "indent": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the only combination that I can get VSCode (and husky/prettier) to stop making an indent 3 spaces. I'm flabbergasted. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious here, this seems like a lot of configuration just to avoid 3 spaces, also who wants 3 spaces for an indent? I'd love to know the back story.