# VSCode Flutter refuses to indent with 4 spaces

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, tabs

I find it incredibly distracting to code with 2 spaces indentation, so I always set my indentation size to 4 spaces, however, on this flutter project, the indentation stays at 2 spaces, no matter what I change, it refuses to be 4 spaces... (this applies to all files, not just the main.dart file)

[image: Example of spaces in my code]

I've tried setting indentation spaces to 4 from 2 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37077167/15586166 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398290/15586166) but even when it is set to 4 spaces for Dart specific projects (the json file), workspace settings (assuming frontend for json file) and in the VSCode user settings tab, it goes back to 2 spaces on format (or rather the settings stays at 4 spaces, but it still formats at 2 spaces). I do not have a `.editorconfig`, so I couldn't change it there. I've also disabled detect indentations (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809036/15586166) on all the levels I did with the indentations sizes.

[image: JSON settings]

[image: User settings]

[image: VSCode spaces display preview]

Could it be that [dart_style](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_style) (which I am assuming is formatting the code), enforces 2 spaces indentations? If it is, is it possible to change it?

[image: dart style enabled]

Although, taking a look through its code, it shouldn't be enforcing 2 spaces, like this [function](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/blob/master/lib/src/dart_formatter.dart#L50). (see image)

[image: Code Snippet]

I also only have these 2 extensions for Dart/Flutter, and only Prettier formatter (only other formatter), but disabling it does not fix the issue...

[image: Extensions]

Comment: Tbh with how flutter is structured it's better to use 2 spaces.

Comment: @LacticWhale Yeah, I guess, if I can't change it, then I'll make do, it's not the end of the world, just an annoyance

Comment: it also annoyed hell out of me XD. But later I noticed how "hilly" flutter code is.

Comment: I fail to see "with how flutter is structured it's better to use 2 spaces". How does indenting with 4 spaces make one iota of difference to the language? I just started looking at Flutter but forcing me to not see the code indentation clearly enough is going to make life a living hell.

Comment: I am surprised tabs aren't used. At least with a tab, people can choose how much space a tab takes, 2, 4, 8.  Whitespace _is_ important. It is exhausting reading Flutter. After a while, all the code just looks the same "WidgetFormchildchildrenconstContainer". I imagine Flutter is very difficult on people with vision impairments.

Answer (score 3):

For those who tired to wait a customisation from Dart guys here is a solution: fork the dart_style repository, change to own needs and setup the replacement to be used in VSCode. Instruction (and ready patch) is [here](https://github.com/mkakabaev/dart_style)